# React render got a warning need a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
{storeAvailableHours.map((e,i) => {

                    return(
                    <Dropdown.Item as="button" onClick= {() => {setOrderIndex(i)}} >
                    {e.dayOfWeek}
                    </Dropdown.Item>
                    )

                 })}
```

Hi, everyone.
I got a warning "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop" for this map function.
Do you have any idea how to fix it? Thank you very much.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#basic-list-component

Comment: Did you Google the error and read the other million posts about this? Did you read up about what the "key" prop is in React - what it means and when you need it? Google is your friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the `key` prop to the item.

```
<Dropdown.Item key={i} as="button" onClick= {() => {setOrderIndex(i)}} >
 {e.dayOfWeek}
</Dropdown.Item>
```